Raster legend shows erroneous range, selecting Actual Min/Max Value Settings doesn't fix it
I ran Fill Sinks (Wang & Liu) on a small DEM. The elevation range on the input was about 39 to 235. The range for the output was about 128 to 771.
My understanding of this tool is that it should be getting rid of concave areas with no outlet, not stretching the whole DEM. What could be going on?
Update: The erroneous range is actually on the original DEM. The Fill Sinks output shows the correct values. Selecting Actual (slower) Accuracy and Min / Max on the Layer Styling panel doesn't change anything.


128/39=3.28
771/235=3.28
I don't know anything about Fill Sinks, but I do know a Feet/Meter problem when I see one.
